# Setup different codestyle schemes for lagnuages

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there is a possibility to use different predefined codestyle schemas in IntelliJ Idea for Java and Javascript? Each time I select the schema it applies to all language editors, not just to a selected one as I expected.

Comment: There are two menu items in code style settings - Java and JavaScript. What problem do you face keeping them under one scheme?

Comment: The problem was that I have to use Google code style which overrides the Javascript code style, though I have a different schema for it. But you gave me the idea that I can just copy a part with Javascript from the second schema and replace it inside the Google code style xml. That answers my question, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work, because there's a lot of options that specified not for each language editor but for all of them at the same time, like TAB_SIZE, USE_TAB_CHARACTER, etc. Not sure why it was designed this way, but guess that's why you can't select different schema for different coding languages.

Comment: TAB_SIZE and USE_TAB_CHARACTER exists for Java and JavaScript languages separately. So you could import Google code style and then change settings in JavaScript settings. As a result you'll get Google style for Java and custom style for JavaScript. Doesn't it work for you?